# Variable scoping across <?php ...?> blocks with HTML interspersed

Tags: php, html, scope

I am very new to webscripting and technologies. So please pardon me if this is a very basic query. Further I have been researching this all day and I haven't been able to figure out why this is not working.

I am essentially trying to improve a website for my wife. The design dictates that we have a common header.php file that can be included into the various static pages that the website contains.

Now as a new requirement, they want to target a few static pages targeting different keywords, and for this the company wants to setup a different "Heading Message". So I want to dynamically pass a different "$page_heading" before I include my header.php.

My header.php has a bunch of HTML code with  interspersed in between , so the following doesn't seem to be working:

```
    In <mypage.php>:
    ...
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <?php 
                //global page_header;
                $page_header = 'A Wildlife Resort of South India';
                include('header.php'); 
            ?>
    ...
    In <header.php>:
    <header class="row-fluid">
        <div class="header-main">
                <a href="http://www.innthewild.com" class="pull-left"><img src="http://www.innthewild.com/img/itw-logo.png" alt="Inn The Wild" style="margin-top:8px;"/></a>
            <div class="pull-right" style="height: 20px;">
                <nav>
    ...
        <div class="heading pull-right">
            <?php
                    if(!isset($page_heading)) {
                        $page_heading = 'A Wilderness Retreat &mdash; Masinagudi Jungle Resort, India';
                }
                echo $page_heading;
            ?>
        </div>
    ...
```

The above seems like it should work straight up, but the variable seems to be losing its scope across a new  instance. How do I make this work?

Here are the example pages: http://www.innthewild.com and http://innthewild.com/resorts-places-around-bangalore.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling it `$page_header` in `mypage.php` and `$page_heading` in `header.php`.

Change one or the the other so that the variable name matches across them

Comment: Jeez!! That was embarrassing! I guess that is what happens when you are focused more on what else could be wrong and miss something as basic as this! Thanks very much DaveyBoy! I cant believe I wasted hours on this today! :-)

Comment: No prob. I've done it loads of times even in the same script without including any other files

Answer (score 0):

u don't need to pass it

```
$some_var = "text";
include "some.php";
```

the script you just included can access the $some_var

Comment: Thanks very much for your response mc_fish. I already have that in the code above (see the example code above), and it doesn't work. See the variable $page_header and I always get 'A Wilderness Retreat &mdash; Masinagudi Jungle Resort, India' instead of 'A Wildlife Resort of South India'